# How to convert a string containing AM/PM to DateTime?

Tags: c#

How can i parse a string like this: "2/22/2015 9:54:02 AM" to a DateTime instance?

i am currently using the DateTime.ParseExact method but without the AM/PM
i.e:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("2/22/2015 9:54:02", "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

I would like to be able to parse the AM/PM signs as well.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should change the hour format (`H`) to lowercase like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2/22/2015 9:54:02 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Uppercase "H" indicates a 24-hour time and lowercase "h" indicates 12-hour time and will respect the AM/PM in the candidate string.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `tt` specifier:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
    "2/22/2015 9:54:02 PM",
    "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
)
```

However be warned this can be locale specific. Also `HH` refers to the 24 hour clock, with AM/PM you generally use the 12 hour clock, so you'd want to use `hh` or just `h` for that.

Comment: This function do not take 2 arguments

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2/22/2015 9:54:02 PM", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (date.Contains("AM") || date.Contains("PM"))
    return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```