# Set am or pm String to Date Time Format in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have

```
int year=2017;
int month=02;
int day=01;
int hour=11;
int minutes=30;
String format="AM";

DateTime datetime=new DateTime(year,month,day,hour,minutes,0);
```

So how can i add this `AM` or `PM` format `string` to datetime?

Comment: Did you search something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string containing AM/PM to DateTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672191/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-am-pm-to-datetime)

Comment: Yep, They say to change from string.format() to date time.I just want to known can i add this format when i create new date time.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a condition:

```
int year = 2017;
int month = 2;
int day = 1;
int hour = 11;
int minutes = 30;
String format = "AM";

DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, 
                                 month, 
                                 day, 
                                 (format.ToUpperInvariant() == "PM" && hour < 12) ? 
                                     hour + 12 : hour, 
                                 minutes, 
                                 00);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the following way:

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt");
```

Its the 'tt' that adds the am/pm. Take a look at the MSDN docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I guess the op wants to have the reversed process. Constructing the `DateTime` from this information that you are printing with `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: [Convert to DateTime with AM/PM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672247/5174469)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2/22/2015 9:54:02 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In your case:

```
int year=2017;
int month=02;
int day=01;
int hour=11;
int minutes=30;
String format="AM";

DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact($"{month}/{day}/{year} {hour}:{minutes}:00 {format}",
             "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```