# C# - How to parse datetime string "Mar 25 2014 10:15:58:757AM"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How to parse a this datetime string in c#

```
 Mar 25 2014 10:15:58:757AM
```

I have tried this, but not working.

```
DateTime val = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStringValue, "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:fffTT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string containing AM/PM to DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672191/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-am-pm-to-datetime)

Comment: “But not working” is not a question; please tell us what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) are *case sensitive*.

That's why you should use `tt` instead of `TT`.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mar 25 2014 10:15:58:757AM", 
                    "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:ffftt", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```